# Why does the code run with bots?

Tags: javascript, php, apache

I have this code in my header, which supposed to redirect users to another page if they have specific old browsers.
I do not want this javascript code to be executed when bots are accessing the site. I have created a PHP condition for that, but my httpd access logs still shows that the bots are running this code.
I know that because I am using JSNlog to log javascript errors and they trigger error when executing my code.

This is my code:

```
<?php
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']) && preg_match('/bot|crawl|slurp|spider/i', $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])) {
    //do nothing
}else{
    ?>

<script type="text/javascript">
function getBrowserData(nav) {
    var data = {};

    var ua = data.uaString = nav.userAgent;
    var browserMatch = ua.match(/(opera|chrome|safari|firefox|msie|trident(?=\/))\/?\s*([\d\.]+)/i) || [];
    if (browserMatch[1]) { browserMatch[1] = browserMatch[1].toLowerCase(); }
    var operaMatch = browserMatch[1] === 'chrome';
    if (operaMatch) { operaMatch = ua.match(/\bOPR\/([\d\.]+)/); }

    if (/trident/i.test(browserMatch[1])) {
        var msieMatch = /\brv[ :]+([\d\.]+)/g.exec(ua) || [];
        data.name = 'msie';
        data.version = msieMatch[1];
    }
    else if (operaMatch) {
        data.name = 'opera';
        data.version = operaMatch[1];
    }
    else if (browserMatch[1] === 'safari') {
        var safariVersionMatch = ua.match(/version\/([\d\.]+)/i);
       if (safariVersionMatch !== null) {
        data.name = 'safari';
        data.version = safariVersionMatch[1];
       }
    }
    else {
        data.name = browserMatch[1];
        data.version = browserMatch[2];
    }

    var versionParts = [];
    if (data.version) {
        var versionPartsMatch = data.version.match(/(\d+)/g) || [];
        for (var i=0; i < versionPartsMatch.length; i++) {
            versionParts.push(versionPartsMatch[i]);
        }
        if (versionParts.length > 0) { data.majorVersion = versionParts[0]; }
    }
    data.name = data.name || '(unknown browser name)';
    data.version = {
        full: data.version || '(unknown full browser version)',
        parts: versionParts,
        major: versionParts.length > 0 ? versionParts[0] : '(unknown major browser version)'
    };

    return data;
};

  var brData = getBrowserData(window.navigator || navigator);

  if (
      (brData.name == 'opera' && brData.version.major < 10) ||
      (brData.name == 'msie' && brData.version.major < 10) ||
      (brData.name == 'firefox' && brData.version.major < 27) ||
      (brData.name == 'safari' && brData.version.major < 6)
      ) {

  window.location = "https://www.example.com/outdated.htm";

  }
// }


</script>


<?php } ?>
```

This is the error I see in the Apache log:

```
 "POST /jsnlog.logger.php HTTP/1.1" 200 40 "https://www.example.com/some-url" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)"
```

Which matches my JSNlog error log:

```
[JSPHPLog]: {"msg":"Exception!","errorMsg":"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of null","url":""https://www.example.com/some-url","line number":186}
```

Line 186 is one of the lines from the above javascript code.

Am I doing something wrong with my condition? How can I make bots not run/see this code?

Comment: and wich line is that?

Comment: try `console.log(browserMatch)`, I think, there will be the error.

Comment: I am not 100% sure which line, because the way JSNlog counts lines is different than the way I see it, but it's definitely in the same block of code. The point is that the js not supposed to run at all afaik, which is what the questions is about.